# What is my strategy once I have chosen an $\epsilon$ in open/closed set proofs?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I have read many questions similar to this one but none have really  been able to answer my question.

Assume I have a set $$S= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \vert x>1, y>1 \right\}$$

I want to determine if this set is open or closed. From the definition:

> Let $V$ be a normed vector space then $O \subset V$ is an open set if:
>
> $$\forall x \in O \space \exists \space \epsilon >0 : N_{\epsilon}(x) \subset O$$
> where the neighbourhood of $x$ is defined as:
>
> $$N_{\epsilon}(x):= \left\{x \in V \vert d(x,x_0) <\epsilon \right\}$$

So I have to find an $\epsilon$ s.t. the disc (in $\mathbb R^2$) around any point in the set  $S$ is still contained within the set. There are two problems that I don't understand:

1. Is there any strategy for chosing $\epsilon$? I have read many answers to similar questions that either brush over the choice or refer to the choice as "art" or "intuition".
2. Assuming I have chosen a suitable $\epsilon$. What do I need to show then? In other words, how do I continue to show that this choice of epsilon ensures that any disc drawn with radius $\epsilon$ around an arbitrary point $x_0$ is contained within the set.

**Edit: Based on the comments here is my attempt:**

Geometrically it looks like this:

[image]

I was thinking to let $\epsilon$ be $\frac{\min\left((x_0-1),(y_0-1)\right)}{2}$. Given any point $P \in S$, take the distance to the line $x=1$ and $y=1$ and choose the smaller of the distances. Then, construct a circle with radius of half that distance and all $(x,y)$ in that circle will be in $S$. I just don't know how to formally write this down and PROVE that this is the case. I have started by writing:

$$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y
-y_0)^2}<\epsilon = \frac{\min\left((x_0-1),(y_0-1)\right)}{2}$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Figure out the boundary and calculate distance to it

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry for the late reply. As far as I understand, my boundries are $x=1$ and $y=1$. My strategy is then to calculate the distance to these boundries with my chosen $\epsilon$. Assume I chose $\epsilon= \frac{\lvert \vec{x_0}\rvert-1}{2}$ (not sure if thats a good choice) for my example. Do i then calculate $x\pm \epsilon$ and $y\pm \epsilon$ to see if they are still in $S$?

Comment: It's necessary to have those four points included, but not sufficient (you need the whole epsilon ball included). Literally just set epsilon to be the distance to the boundary and calculate what that is (it will be the minimum of the distances to the left edge and the bottom edge, both of which are just either distance formula or just subtracting one coordinate value from the other). There's no cleverness or thought needed here at all.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I have edited my question with an attempt. Maybe you could take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: You use the triangle inequality @qmd. Your choice of epsilon is perfect though. I would write out the details, but it looks like other people have already answered your question :)

Comment: As an aside, once you prove the topological definition of openness aligns with the epsilon definition for any metric space, this becomes a lot easier since you can prove $\{ x : f(x) > g(x) \} $ is open for any continuous functions $f$ and $g$, and the subset in your question is just the intersection of two such sets (and finite intersection of open sets is open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise that it is important to distinguish between the are arbitrary $P$ so that $P\in S$ (which indicated as $P=(x_0,y_0)$; that's fine) and the arbitrary $Q\in N_\epsilon ((x_0,y_0))$.  You are implying that you choose $x,y$ to be the arbitrary point $(x,y)\in N_\epsilon((x_0,y_0))$, which is okay, but it it is easy to get confused and think that $x,y$ are variables rather than an arbitrary (any) point in $N_\epsilon((x_0,y_0))$.

I'd prefer you had said:  Let $(u,w) \in N_\epsilon((x_0,y_0))$.

Now you know $\sqrt{(u-x_0)^2+(w-y_0)^2} < \epsilon = \min(\frac {x_0-1}2,\frac {y_0-1}2)$. and you want to prove $u>1, w>1$.

Now one very useful trick when dealing with Euclidean distance of $\sqrt{(u-x_0)^2+(w-y_0)^2}$ and wanting to avoid complex quadratics is to note that.

$\sqrt{(u-x_0)^2 + (w-y_0)^2} \ge \sqrt{(u-x_0)^2} = |u-x_0|$ and $\sqrt{(u-x_0)^2 + (w-y_0)^2} \ge \sqrt{(w-y_0)^2} = |w-y_0|$

So if you have

$\sqrt{(u-x_0)^2 + (w-y_0)^2}  < \epsilon \implies$

$|u-x_0| \le \sqrt{(u-x_0)^2 + (w-y_0)^2} < \epsilon$ and $|w-y_0|\le \sqrt{(u-x_0)^2 + (w-y_0)^2}  < \epsilon$

[It's very important to realize that is an $\implies$ and not an $\iff$.]

So we have $|u-x_0| < \min(\frac {x_0-1}2, \frac {y_0-1}2) \le \frac {x_0-1}2$.
And $|w-y_0| < \min(\frac {x_0-1}2, \frac {y_0-1}2) \le \frac {y_0 - 1}2$

Now heres the other trick.  When you have $|u - c| < \epsilon$ for some constant $c$ then you also have $-\epsilon < -|u-c|$ and as $u-c$ is equal to either $\pm|u-c|$ we have $-\epsilon < u-c < \epsilon$ and therefore $c-\epsilon < u < \epsilon$

So using that we have

$x_0 - \frac {x_0-1}2 = \frac {x_0}2 + \frac 12 < u < x_0 + \frac{x_0-1}2 = \frac 32x_0 -\frac 12$.

Now $x_0 > 1$ so $\frac{x_0}2 + \frac 12 > \frac 12 +\frac 12 = 1$.  (And $\frac 32x_0 -\frac 12 > 1$ as well, but that will not be useful)

So we have $1 < \frac {x_0}2 +\frac 12 < u$ so $u > 1$.  We are half done!  (The $\frac 23x_0 - \frac 12 > 1$ along with $u < \frac 23x_0 - \frac 12$ doesn't get us anywhere because the inequalities aren't in agreement.  All we know is $u < $ something that is bigger than $1$ and that's useless as *everything* is smaller than *something* bigger than $1$.)

The other half is the exact same way:

$|w-y_0| < \frac {y_0 - 1}2\implies$

$y_0 -\frac {y_0-1}2 < w < y_0 + \frac {y_0 - 1}2\implies$

$1 = \frac 12 + \frac 12 < y_0 -\frac {y_0-1}2 < w$

So $u>1$ and $w>1$ so $(u,w)\in S$.

And as $(u,w)\in N_\epsilon((x_0,y_0))$ was completely arbitrary $N_\epsilon((x_0,y_0)) \subset S$.  And as $(x_0, y_0) \in S$ was completely arbitrary that conditions applies to all points in $S$.

Thus $S$ is open.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This one just clicked for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

To get to the $\epsilon$ in the first place, one usually solves those inequalities in rough.

Then, in the proof, you start off with that $\epsilon$, and prove that the $\epsilon$ satisfies the needed inequalities and hence the hypothesis.

Here, once you choose the suitable $\epsilon$, prove that every point within $\epsilon$ distance lies within the set.

Given $x, y > 1$ :
Let $x = 1 + \epsilon_1$, $y = 1 + \epsilon_2$

Choose $\epsilon = \dfrac{\min(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)}{2}$ 
Note that $0 <\epsilon < \epsilon_1$ and $0 <\epsilon < \epsilon_2$

Now consider any point $(a, b)$ that is within $\epsilon$-distance of $(x, y)$.

We'll show that $(a, b)$ is within the set, that is $a>1, b>1$

Let's start with the fact that $(a, b)$ is within $\epsilon$-distance of $(x, y)$.

That is, $|(a, b)-(x, y)| \leq \epsilon$

By the Pythagorean theorem / Triangle Inequality, we have: 
$|(a, b)-(x, y)| \geq |a-x|$ and also $|(a, b)-(x, y)| \geq |b-y|$

Thus we have $|a-x| \leq \epsilon < \epsilon_1$ 
Thus, $a-x > -\epsilon_1$ 
Thus, $a > x - \epsilon_1 > 1$

Similarly for $b$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank your very much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can formally prove this from what you have written.

We need to prove that $x -1 > 0$ and $y - 1>0$. We have that $\sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2} < \epsilon$ using your $\epsilon$. The value of $(x_0-x)^2$ itself is bounded by $\epsilon^2$, if it were not, you you have the point $(x, y_0)$ outside your circle because it would violate the above inequality. Similarly, $(y_0 - y)^2 < \epsilon^2$.

Assume without loss of generality that $x < x_0$. Otherwise, transitivity of $<$ shows that $x > x_0 > 1$, which is what you wanted to prove. Then we have that $(x_0 - x) < \epsilon$ (because $(x_0 - x)$ is positive so we can take square roots above) and so $x - x_0 > -\epsilon$.

We then have that:
$$x - 1 = (x - x_0) + (x_0 - 1) > -\epsilon + (x_0 - 1) > 0$$

where the last inequality follows from the definition of $min$.

Do the same for $y$ and you are done.

Comment: $>=$ can be written as $\geq$ with `\geq`.

Comment: Thank you, though I just meant to write "=" in any case

Comment: Thank your very much for your answer! :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can proceed:

$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\epsilon = \frac{\min\left((x_0-1),(y_0-1)\right)}{2}\implies$

$\implies |x-x_0|\le \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\epsilon \implies$

$ \implies x>x_0-\epsilon\ge x_0-(x_0-1)=1\implies x>1.$

And similarly $y>1.$

Comment: This doesn't follow $x_0 -\epsilon \not \ge x_0 - (x_0 - 1)$ unless $x_0 -1 \ge \epsilon = \frac {\min(x_0-1), (y_0-1))}2$ which need not be true.

Comment: @fleablood . Since $x_0>1$ we have $\epsilon =\frac {\min (x_0,-1,y_0-1)}{2} \le \frac {x_0-1}{2}<x_0-1.$